# Why am I getting this error and how do I fix it?

Tags: php, oracle, zend-framework, tns

I have written a PHP script to pull a query from an Oracle database and write results to a csv file. I am using Zend Framework to get connected to the database. I know the credentials are correct as I am able to connect through terminal using SQLPlus.

This is the error:

`Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception: SQLSTATE[HY000]: pdo_oci_handle_factory: ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor (/home/http/php-5.3.3/ext/pdo_oci/oci_driver.c:579) in /opt/http/Zend/ZendFramework-1.10.3/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php on line 144`

I have tried to do research, but no solid solutions. I did read that it could be associated with the tnsnames.ora but I couldn't find that file on the server. I have used Zend before in other projects without any issues.

FYI: I do not have root, so I can't do much magic on the server.

What are your suggestions?

Comment: try tnsping on cmd line for that SID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a common errormessage from Oracle, there is nothing to do with zend or even php. I usually get this message in SQLDeveloper or Toad. Check the tnsnames.ora, listener.ora, sqlnet.ora, log files etc. and try to connect with a client app. (if it isn't working, you can report it to the admins)

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a file called tnsnames.ora in your `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin` folder and put in it your SID .

or if you can't create your tnsnames.ora, try setting your DB config using this syntax :

```
$config = new Zend_Config(
array(
'database' => array(
'adapter' => 'oracle',
'params' => array(
    'dbname'=> '(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hostname.domain.tld)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = service_name)))',
    'username' => 'dev',
    'password' => 'pwd')
    )
)
);
$db = Zend_Db::factory($config->database);
Zend_Db_Table::setDefaultAdapter($db);
```

Althought its better to create tnsnames.ora with your DB config.

Comment: I would love an explanation as to the black magic involved with that connection string but it fixed things for me.

Answer (score 2):

For those not using Zend Framework, but having similar issue, a solution to this problem can be found on http://docs.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-oci.php#64756

```
$tns = "  
(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = yourip)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
       ";
$db_username = "youname";
$db_password = "yourpassword";
try{
    $conn = new PDO("oci:dbname=".$tns,$db_username,$db_password);
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo ($e->getMessage());
}
```

If you're using SID to connect, change

```
(SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
```

to

```
(SID = yourSid)
```